# Entity Framework Installation Fails & Crashes Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to install Entity Framework 5.0 into a Visual Studio 2012 Pro project.  Part way through the install it fails and crashes Visual Studio.  I suspect that it is trying to figure out which SQL server edition to use when it fails.  I have SQL 2008 R2, SQL 2012 and SQL 2012 Localdb installed.  No connection string gets added to the config file before it crashes.  I've been searching the forums and trying many things but no luck yet.  Any help would be appreciated.  Same failure when using Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

Comment: What do you mean by "installation". Is it just adding package to  project? Btw. it doesn't add any connection string to your configuration file. It only adds connection factory.

Comment: Yes.  I installed the NuGet installer and then try to istall t5he framework when it crashes.  The installer is supossed to check SQL editions and add that info to the project config file.  This is not happening.

Comment: No.  Not EF Power Tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the EF installer can't handle multiple versions of SQL installed side by side.  After removing all but one the program runs fine.